# Can I calculate the Covariance Matrix of the sum of a random vector with a transformation of itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance

I am trying to calculate the Covariance matrix of the following random vector:

$Y = X-AX$

where $X$ is a random vector with $n$ entries and $A: n\times n$ transformational matrix where each entry is in the interval $[0,1]$.

I also know that the mean of all entries in $X$ is zero: $E(X) = 0$ and I know the Covariance matrix of $X$ as $\Sigma_X$.

I feel like I have everything to calculate $\Sigma_Y$ but I can't really wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying covariance definition is enough. Let's start computing first moments of $Y$:
$$E[Y] = E[X-AX] = (I-A)E[X] = 0$$

\begin{align*}
E[YY^T] & = E[(X-AX)(X-AX)^T] \\
& = E[XX^T-XX^TA^T-AXX^T+AXX^TA^T] \\
& = \Sigma_X-\Sigma_XA^T-A\Sigma_X+A\Sigma_XA^T \\
\end{align*}
Now, using these expressions you can handle $\Sigma_Y$
\begin{align*}
\Sigma_Y&=E[YY^T] = E[(Y-E[Y])(Y-E[Y])^T]\\
& = E[YY^T]-E[Y]E[Y]^T\\
& = \Sigma_X-\Sigma_XA^T-A\Sigma_X+A\Sigma_XA^T\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! :-)